# Solving $\nabla \times \mathbf{b} = \mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{a}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, cross-product, foliations

Suppose we are given a fixed vector field $\mathbf{a}$. I am interested in the problem of determining a vector field $\mathbf{b}$ such that 
$$\nabla \times \mathbf{b} = \mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{a}.$$
This has another interpretation. Suppose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the 1-forms dual to $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$. The above equation can be written as
$$d \beta = \beta \wedge \alpha,$$ 
and so we can interpret this problem as finding, for a fixed 1-form $\alpha$, a foliation $\mathcal{F} = \text{ker}\ \beta$ such that $\alpha$ determines the Godbillon-Vey class of $\mathcal{F}$.

It seems unlikely to me that a solution always exists, but I have been unable to prove anything beyond the obvious fact that we must have $\mathbf{b} \cdot \nabla \times \mathbf{b} = 0$, and that $\mathbf{b} \cdot \nabla \times \mathbf{a} = \mathbf{a} \cdot \nabla \times \mathbf{b}$ (take the divergence), which implies (Mark's comment) that $\mathbf{b}$ is orthogonal to $\nabla \times \mathbf{a}$.

Are there any known results about such equations, or techniques one could use to construct a solution other than crunching through the PDEs for each component?

Comment: I can't go into any detail on this, but I've understood that geometric algebra/clifford algebra makes solving equations like this easy

Comment: We have $$\vec a\cdot \nabla \times \vec b=\vec b\cdot \nabla \times \vec b=0$$

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'll look into it. Perhaps someone will elaborate.

Comment: What is known about $\mathbf{a}$?

Comment: @md2perpe In my case I know that $\mathbf{a} \cdot \nabla \times \mathbf{a} \neq 0$, but nothing else. I'd like to know what's possible in the greatest generality but if additional assumptions allow an easier solution that's interesting too.

Comment: Actually, I would also like to impose the constraint $\mathbf{b} = \mathbf{a} \times (\nabla \times \mathbf{a})$. With this extra constraint I don't think it's true that solutions always exist over the reals - setting $\mathbf{a} = (1,0,-y)$ I get $\mathbf{b} = (0, \pm i, 0)$.

Comment: If $\mathbf{a} = -\nabla\phi$ then $\mathbf{b} = e^\phi \mathbf{c}$ is a solution where $\mathbf{c}$ is a constant vector.

Comment: Interesting. Then perhaps we can use the Helmholtz decomposition to write $\mathbf{a} = -\nabla \phi + \nabla \times \mathbf{d}$ to make further progress.

Comment: @JoePollard, are given field $\vec a$ constant?

Comment: @MichaelGaluza It should depend on position.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small set of solutions. Let $p$ and $q$ be any numbers
and $c$ any constant vector. Then
$$
      b(x) = |x|^p x\times (x\times c),
  \qquad\qquad
      a(x) = (p+3)\frac{x}{|x|^2}+qb(x)
$$
is a solution.  Here $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $|x|$ is Euclidean norm.

Edit: your comment about $a$ rules out gradients, but I'll mention anyway more solutions when $a = \nabla g$. Using $\nabla\times(h\nabla f) = \nabla h\times\nabla f$ you get
$$
 \nabla\times(e^{-g}\nabla f) = e^{-g}\nabla f \times \nabla g.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see that these work, but is there some particular technique you used to arrive at this answer?

Comment: When working with cross products I've sometimes found it useful to
use linear combinations of the vector fields $x$, $x\times c$ and $x\times(x\times c)$.
They are orthogonal for most values of $x$, and work well under
crossing with $x$, since $x\times(x\times(x\times c))) = -|x|^2 x\times c$.
Since these fields have been helpful more than once, does that
qualify it as a "technique?" I started with $c=(1,0,0)$ because
that is enough by linearity and symmetry, and is easy to work with.

Comment: I see, thank you for explaining.